# Squeezenet on ios

Tags: ios, coreml

I am trying to use Squeezenet ML Model provided by Apple in an iOS app.  When I pass an image for classification, the predictions are way off.  I suspect that the problem is due to the fact that the typical preprocessing for images provided to Squeezenet for classification have not been implemented in the iOS app.  In particular, when implemented in Python, the following preprocessing steps are required for an image:

```
model = SqueezeNet()

img = image.load_img('cat.jpeg', target_size=(227, 227))
x = image.img_to_array(img)        #Preprocess Step 1
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)      #Preprocess Step 2
x = preprocess_input(x)            #Preprocess Step 3

preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds))
```

Does anyone know how to recreate these three preprocessing steps in iOS?

**Update following comment from Matthijs:**

Matthijs, I have seen your blog post and understand the need to perform the same preprocessing.  I have made changes to my code for the image that is submitted to the model and am getting better results.  However, it is still not clear to me if the preprocessing is being handled by the model per your blog post or if the format of the image data I am passing to the Apple Squeezenet model is incorrect.

For example, here are some comparison results for Squeezenet in Python vs what I am getting from Apple's Squeezenet mode in my app (both models correctly classified the image unless noted):

```
Image          Confidence value
Samoyed dog    0.899 (Python model with preprocess_input applied)
Samoyed dog    0.994 (Python model without preprocess_input applied)
Samoyed dog    0.837 (Apple model)
Beagle dog     0.962 (Python model with preprocess_input applied)
Beagle dog     0.975 (Python model without preprocess_input applied)
Beagle dog*    0.626 (Apple model)
* Apple model incorrectly classified as Labrador Retriever
Tabby cat      0.863 (Python model with preprocess_input applied)
Tabby cat      0.986 (Python model without preprocess_input applied)
Tabby cat      0.995 (Apple model)
```

Any thoughts as to whether this is a preprocessing issue or something else?  Could it be that the format of the image submitted to the model is incorrect?  Is there a way to see what preprocessing steps (if any) are performed by a CoreML model?

Comment: This question gets asked so often I wrote a blog post about it: http://machinethink.net/blog/help-core-ml-gives-wrong-output/

Although if you're using Apple's SqueezeNet model you'd think they supplied the correct preprocessing options when they created the .mlmodel file. How are you passing the image to Core ML and how "way off" are the predictions?

Comment: Matthijs, thanks for your response.  See the update above.

Comment: You will see some slight variation in classification confidence values and results running on iOS vs. a desktop platform due to the difference in running inference with 32-bit floats (desktop) vs. 16-bit floats (mobile). Aside from checking to see that Apple's model was taking in BGR (it should, if they translated the trained Caffe model), I don't believe the original SqueezeNet model used mean subtraction or other preprocessing.